# Posting text on a facebook page from an android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an android app which integrates with facebook(I'm very new).I could successfully implement the login/logout part.
Now I need my android app to post(text) on a specific page.I'm not sure how to approach this. I tried reading all the similar posts. I used "facebook.request(page_id+/feed , parameters , "POST")" ,this always returned a null pointer exception maybe because the `request(feed,parameters,"POST")` method is deprecated (code written below).
I tried to follow the facebook sdk tutorial which involved access_tokens and graph apis which further confused me. 
I don't even know how to approach this anymore.Please, if someone could guide me it would be a lot helpful and easier for me to go about this. 
Thank you.

```
try{
  Tring response = facebook.request("me");
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", msg);
    parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
    // parameters.putByteArray("message", msg);
    response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
    Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
    if (response == null || response.equals("")
            || response.equals("false")) {
        Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
     }else{


    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

}

```
LOGCAT
01-07 20:14:21.330    7830-7835/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-07 20:16:21.460  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 V/Zygote﹕ Switching descriptor 33 to /dev/null
01-07 20:16:21.460  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 V/Zygote﹕ Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null
01-07 20:16:21.470  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-07 20:16:21.710  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:com.example.kai.gameofapis2
01-07 20:16:21.720  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
01-07 20:16:21.720  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
01-07 20:16:22.301  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 I/MainFragment﹕ Logged in...
01-07 20:16:22.471  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-07 20:16:22.701  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-07 20:16:22.701  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-07 20:16:22.831  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-07 20:16:22.831  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 I/MainFragment﹕ Logged in...
01-07 20:16:22.951  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41d82b18 time:64292484
01-07 20:16:30.539  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.kai.gameofapis2.MainFragment$2.onClick(MainFragment.java:75)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5153)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
01-07 20:16:30.549  11583-11583/com.example.kai.gameofapis2 W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You said `always returned a null pointer exception maybe because the request(feed,parameters,"POST") method is deprecated` which can never true. NullPointerException is caused when you try to use a object which is null. We can help you if you post your complete logcat error output.

Comment: Post the logcat please

Comment: Sorry about that,I have update my post with the logcat.